# Show data from db into another div (from selected $rowId )

Tags: php, mysql, html, hyperlink

I'm having problems with showing data from a selected row into another div.

Meaning I'm showing eg forename and lastname, when the user clicks on the name (as a link), I would like to show more data from the Id chosen, and I would like it to be shown in a div box below.

See the site here: http://kristoff.it/onlinecoaching/

And my code:

```
<div class="greenBox1">
        <h1>1 - VÆLG DIN ONLINE COACH</h1>
            <div class="whiteBox1">
                <?php   
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM coach ";

                    $coachId = $row["coachId"];
                    $fornavn = $row["fornavn"];
                    $efternavn = $row["efternavn"];

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);                
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {   

                        echo '<table border="0" align="left" height="100">';
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td width="95" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><img src="' . $row['imgUrl'] . '" width="85" height="85" alt="' . $row['imgAlt'] . '"/>' . '</td>'; 
                    ?>  
                        <!-- here I'm trying to write the id of the selected name to the div box below -->                              
                    <?  
                        echo '<td><a href="' . $coachId . '" target="whiteBox2"><h2>' . $row['fornavn'] . $row['efternavn'] . '</h2></a></td>';
                        echo '</tr>';

                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td valign="top" width="190"><p>' . $row['beskrivKort'] . '<br></p></td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        echo '</table>';
                    }                           
                ?>                   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="greenBox2">
        <h1>2 - BOOK TID I COACHENS KALENDER</h1>
            <div class="whiteBox2" id="whiteBox2">
           <!-- here would like the more data to show -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Regards Maria

Comment: what pblm you are facing on this code?

Comment: But still nothing is beeing written

Answer (score 0):

In your website, your URLs are empty. You need to put your ID.

```
echo '<td><a href="URLOFYOURSITE?id=' . $coachId . '" target="whiteBox2"><h2>' . $row['fornavn'] . $row['efternavn'] . '</h2></a></td>';
```

With that URL, you will send the ID as a GET variable.
You must then request your data if the ID is set.

```
<div class="whiteBox2" id="whiteBox2">
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM coach WHERE coachId=" . (int)$_GET['id'];
    // Do your stuff...
    echo "Hello";
}
?>
<!-- here would like the more data to show -->
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, so now its working, thank you guys, thats wonderfull, but I still don't understand why it wants to open the data in the right box BUT I A NEW WINDOW?? Can you please tell me?